# How can I reattach a trim board to my garage door frame?

Tags: garage

I have a trim board detached from the garage external.
It is just decorative.

Can you suggest to me:

1. how to attach it back to its place
2. what products I have to purchase (I am in Italy if it helps)
3. what is the best period to do this kind of jobs considering the temperatures (I am saying this because at the moment we have 0° Celsius (32° Fahrenheit) and I know some glues have issues at these temperatures)?

Thanks for the support.

[image]

[image]

FIXED (Thanks)
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what that board was from way back here. Is it just a decorative trim?

Comment: Certainly looks more like a trim board (decorative) than part of a frame (structural.)

Comment: Do you mean "garage **door** frame"? That is a considerably different item than the structural *frame* of a garage!

Comment: Hi and thanks to everyone. Sorry I was looking for the right term in english and I was in doubt. It seems to me it is a trim board now that I know the term.
Basically the garage door works without any issue.
The only problem I have is that, the trim board is in my garage, but it should be placed in that section I highlighted in the 2nd photo

Comment: Please [edit] this additional info into your question. That will help everyone who comes to read your question now and in the future.

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to simply screw the trim board to the door jamb.

Comment: Hi @Huesmann, there are no holes in the trim board. Those dark spots you see in the photo are just spots where there is no dust

Comment: @Sixro that doesn't mean you can't *make* holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the photo that trim board was originally attached with a bead of caulk. You can see the lingering trail in the wall photo. I'd take the same strategy considering what appears to be stucco on the wall and vinyl on the door frame.

Look for a product that's rated for exterior use, has quick initial grab, and remains flexible. It also needs to be compatible with plastic. Urethane or latex project adhesive might do.

Comment: Thanks @isherwood. Are those products available online or do you think is it better to go to a store that sells products used in construction/building asking for that urethane/latex adhesive?

Comment: Shopping is off topic here. I'm far from Italy. :) I'd expect that either is an option for you. I don't generally buy building materials online, though. That's just me.